# Getting a product only if another product was purchased first?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was looking at [this example of joining multiple tables](http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_linking_table.php) and it had me wondering how you would go about selecting a name from the customers table when for example, the mouse was purchased BEFORE the keyboard?

I was trying something like this, but did not get it working.

```
SELECT 
    product_name, customer.name, date_of_sale 
    FROM sales, product, customer 
    WHERE 
        STR_TO_DATE(
            (
                SELECT date_of_sale 
                FROM sales 
                WHERE product_id = 2
            ),
        STR_TO_DATE('2012-12-23 18:00:00') 

        > 

        STR_TO_DATE(
            (
                SELECT date_of_sale 
                FROM sales 
                WHERE product_id = 3
            ),
        STR_TO_DATE('2012-12-23 18:00:00')
```

Comment: `str_to_date('2012....:00')` is pointless. mysql will accept any string that looks like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` as a valid date-time value already. And if your `date_of_sale` value is ALREADY a datetime value, then it's even more pointless. converting a date to a date is redundant.

Comment: Good to know, +1 to you for informing me, thanks

Comment: I think we need the DESCRIBE table for sales, product and customer to really help you. It's going to be multiple joins - customers and sales (assuming there is a col to join on) and sales to products (again if there are common cols). Good luck. And do you plan to say WHERE customer.name=xxxxxxx or as @may suggested GROUP?

Comment: In the `WHERE`, the first clause is non-boolean. How does this run?

Comment: It would be best if you explain what data you want to get in plain English. We can see the tables in the link.

Comment: @DanVerdolino it does not even remotely run, I just thought that this would be a good way of showing my direction of though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this.

Method one is with a `Unary Join` (`Sales` to `Sales` and then to `Customers`).

Method two is `group_concat` in a `view` (or `temporary table`) `joined to customers`.

**SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a031/22**

### Unary Join

I'm including all the columns for informational reasons.

```
SELECT c.name,
       s1.product_id AS product1,
       s1.date_of_sale AS date1,
       s2.product_id AS product2,
       s2.date_of_sale AS date2
FROM sales s1,
     sales s2,
     customers c
WHERE s1.date_of_sale < s2.date_of_sale
  AND s1.customer_id = s2.customer_id AND
  c.customer_id = s1.customer_id and
  s1.product_id = 3 AND  s2.product_id = 2;
```

### Group_concat in Temp Table

```
SELECT name
FROM customers,
  (SELECT customer_id,
          group_concat(PRODUCT_ID
                       ORDER BY date_of_sale)
   FROM sales
   GROUP BY customer_id HAVING group_concat(PRODUCT_ID
                                            ORDER BY date_of_sale) LIKE '%3,2%') sales_order
WHERE customers.customer_id = sales_order.customer_id;
```

### Pros/Cons

Group Concat:

- PRO: The group_concat method supports multiple values in a row within the like e.g. `LIKE '%3,2,10%'`
- CON: For smaller product tables, it is slower and uses a temporary in-memory table.

Join:

- PRO: Quicker for smaller data sizes.
- CON: Requires +1 sales table in join for +1 product in order.
- CON: Probably slower for larger data sizes

Comment: @ehime Will add also though another solution based on your approach which may be faster.